# Preconfigured Selenium Environments?

Tags: php, selenium

An important benefit of selenium is the simplicity of recording test cases via Firefox Selenium-IDE or [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/). No specific skills needed, it´s almost as easy as clicking "record". Yet somehow running those test cases require the average PHP developer to learn Java and linux administration, among others.

After reading tutorials for the past 5 hours, doing it the hard way seems nowhere withhin budget.

So - is there an easy solution? One of these would be great:

- An online service to upload your test cases, pay a few bucks, and they run them
- A prepared VM you just have to start and copy your test cases
- A bash script you just have to wget & run to set up everything

Thanks

Comment: If you are willing to pay me I can get you up and running :-) Just kidding.. There is a online service http://cloudqa.io/ you can record and playback and they do not use selenium .. you can try if you want

Comment: You might benefit (in getting answers) from making your question a little more specific.

Comment: If you want reliable code, there is no substitute to learning how to code.

Comment: Either code or use a proper DSL or framework. From reading the Selenium forums there seems to have been a realisation that the "record" model tended to produce very brittle (and slow, dumb) tests. I've seen non-technical testers using a good DSL produce robust tests incredibly efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As what you're describing is getting beyond the simplicity of the Selenium IDE there is Selenium WebDriver which I perceive as a Selenium NG and also this is what's mentioned on the main http://www.seleniumhq.org/ page.

So for the simplest case you can go with Selenium IDE add-on. And for any more complex cases Selenium people suggest to use Selenium WebDriver - you can then:

- use prepared [selenium docker images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) (as for the prepared VM) and use simple bash scripts to orchestrate
- use online services like SauceLabs to upload the tests

Still it is possible to save Selenium IDE test as java files and benefit from above techniques however it is not possible to read them again into Selenium IDE.

Comment: I think that's misleading. IDE vs WebDriver is not the simple vs complex option, but the deprecated-for-years vs current option. Nobody should be doing new, serious work in IDE now. Good point on Docker, but you don't really do SauceLabs justice, as it's a grid that can test loads of different browser setups.

Comment: Thanks for good point. Personally as a developer I fully agree and I've also switched to WebDriver many years ago. Yet I've met people who are still happy to use Selenium IDE for simple cases. Actually on seleniumhq.org there is also no information that Selenium IDE is deprecated.